# 400 bad request from inside iframe containing signing URL

Tags: docusignapi

Today we noticed new undesirable behavior from our DocuSign implementation. We are using the embedded signing approach.

Server-side when the form is loading we generate the recipient view URL. This part works fine.

Then we load this URL in an iframe on the form. The iframe only takes up a portion of the form.

Previously this was working fine, but as of today we noticed some errors. The signing ceremony still loads, but we can see errors in the console in Developer Tools. They seem to be coming from inside the iframe. When we remove the iframe the errors go away.

The console in Developer Tools, shows that a 400 (Bad Request) is being received from https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/monitoring?insession=1&ti=4c6f3176cf8841b7885f76a4b5261744 (picture below). This is not a URL that we are calling, so it must be called from within the iframe.

The signing ceremony still works from a user perspective, but this error seems to be halting client-side scripts on the rest of the page. When we remove the iframe, everything else works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

[image: 400 Bad Request - don't yet have 10 reputation to post images]

Comment: You didn't provide the picture...

Comment: Sorry Larry. Apparently I don't know how to embed it so that it shows up in the message. It only shows up if you click the "400 Bad Request" link. I'll try to fix the formatting after I reply to your post down below. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I need a 10 reputation to post images. It forces me to do it as a link. Thanks for the tip though. I now know how to do it when my reputation goes up.

Comment: I upvoted your question so you should be able to post the image now.

Comment: Neato! I have 10 reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally got this working.

We changed this markup:

```
<iframe src="{SigningCeremonyUrl}" />
```

To this markup:

```
<iframe allow="geolocation" src="{SigningCeremonyUrl}"></iframe>
```

As you can see the only differences are:

- Added `allow="geolocation"` (didn't fix the problem by itself)
- Removed self-terminating `<iframe />` tag and used opening and closing tags
  (resolved the issue)

Notable discoveries:

The bug presented itself on 11/10/2017. It was demoed working at 8:00 or 9:00am EST, and then stopped working by the end of the day (3/4/5ish), without any changes being made on our end.

- When we removed the iframe containing the signing ceremony URL, the rest of the page worked fine. Adding it back recreated the issue.
- When changing the URL of the iframe to Google, the rest of the page worked fine. Changing it back recreated the issue.
- When running the signing ceremony URL in the whole window (without the iframe), and with Developer Tools open, it did not throw any JavaScript errors.
- When running in the iframe, and with Developer tools open, the only error we saw was the one posted in the question above.
- When running in the iframe, with self-terminating html tag, we ran the following test, and only received 1 alert:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">alert(0);</script>
  <iframe ... />
  <script type="text/javascript">alert(1);</script>
  ```
- When running in the iframe, and with Developer Tools open, it was as if the our JavaScript wasn't even there. No scripts ran once the iframe loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding the signing ceremony inside an iframe is not recommended.

There are multiple techniques available for maintaining your application's state while the signing ceremony is proceeding. Why do you feel the need for an iFrame?

That said, please provide the envelope_id that had the problem and I'll submit an internal bug report.

Note, the initial url your app receives is not the final url for the signing ceremony. As part of the process, the response to the initial url is a redirect to another. That's been the case for a long time.

Comment: Here is the envelope ID from the create envelope call:
01deac85-63a3-41d9-9b61-2a599169d35c

Here is the signing URL from the create recipient view call (is this not the right URL?):
https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?t=75d71866-54ea-4710-bc72-b986e4afd576

I can generate more if you need.

We are using an iframe because that's what the design team put together. I will push back again on this, but it was working and now all of a sudden it is not. No code changes on our end.

Comment: try deleting all docusign cookies or use an incognito browser tab. Maybe there's a stale cookie.

Comment: Thanks Larry. Just tried running in incognito mode, in a new browser window, in Google Chrome, and still seeing the same error.

Failed to load resource: https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/monitoring?insession=1&ti=ee671382ef0447aeacd750be393f86d7 the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: FYI I'm told that it was working on our DEV servers Friday morning (8ish/9ish EST), and then we started seeing this Friday afternoon. No redeployment to DEV had been made between those 2 times.